# Aren't instances in __init___() reuseable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, class, oop, tf.keras

So I'm currently learning how to create a model in Tensorflow using subclassing. According to the tutorial, the following snippet of code should run perfectly:

```
#Defining the class
class FeatureExtractor(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
        self.batchnorm_1 = BatchNormalization()
        self.maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)

        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
        self.batchnorm_2 = BatchNormalization()
        self.maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)


    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv_1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm_1(x)
        x = self.maxpool_1(x)

        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.batchnorm_2(x)
        x = self.maxpool_2(x)

        return x

#Calling and using the class
feature_extractor = FeatureExtractor()

func_input = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), name="Input_Image")

x = feature_extractor(func_input)
```

And it does indeed run flawlessly. But then I realized that in `__init__()`, the `BatchNormalization()` and `MaxPool2D()` look the same but are defined twice, so I edited it and hence have this class being:

```
#Defining the class
class FeatureExtractor(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
        #Defining batchnorm and maxpool only once
        self.batchnorm = BatchNormalization()
        self.maxpool = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)

        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")


    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv_1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.batchnorm(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        return x
```

But then, I was thrown with a dimension error.

I thought instances in `__init__()` are reuseable? Is it because when layers are called in `call()`, they adapt to the dimension of the input, and then keep that dimension for later calls?

Thank you in advance for your answers. I'm still inexperienced in both Python and Tensorflow, so this might be some basic stuff that I overlooked when learning.

Comment: There is nothing special about `__init__()` here. This is a general question about whether an object can be reused - and that is completely dependent on that object. If it keeps state, then its likely not reusable. Your suspicion that the first use changes something in the object is very reasonable. I can't quite answer this part of the question, so just a comment. But no, there is nothing in python that guarantees that a class instance created in `__init__` is reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought instances in `__init__()` are reuseable?

In general, objects are reusable, but, as tdelaney pointed out in the comments, you need to make sure that the objects state management doesn't get in your way. And this holds everywhere, not just in the `__init__`.

To demonstrate, that reuse works in principle, let's define `MaxPool2D` only once and reuse it, but `BatchNormalization` twice. See here:

```py
from keras import Model, Input
from keras.src.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPool2D


class FeatureExtractor(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Defining maxpool only once
        self.maxpool = MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)

        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=4, padding="valid", activation="relu")
        self.batchnorm1 = BatchNormalization()

        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=4, padding="valid", activation="relu")
        self.batchnorm2 = BatchNormalization()

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv_1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm1(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.batchnorm2(x)
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Calling and using the class
    feature_extractor = FeatureExtractor()
    func_input = Input(shape=(28, 28, 3), name="Input_Image")
    x = feature_extractor(func_input)
```

This version reuses the `maxpool` member, but works fine.

> Is it because when layers are called in call(), they adapt to the dimension of the input, and then keep that dimension for later calls?

This seems to be exactly what's happening here.

Comment: So some layers adapt to the dimension of the input (like batchnorm) and some don't (like maxpool)? Or is there a property of these layers that causes this behavior? (like, how did you know that reusing maxpool would be fine, but not with batchnorm?)

Comment: I'd suggest you ask a different question for that. I honestly don't know enough about the specifics of tensor flow to tell you. But if you have a well titled and appropriately tagged question, someone who does might answer