# Reusability of Layers in Tensorflow Subclassing for Model Creation

Tags: python, tensorflow, oop, tf.keras

So I'm currently learning how to create a model in Tensorflow using subclassing. According to the tutorial, the following snippet of code should run perfectly:

```
#Defining the class
class FeatureExtractor(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
        self.batchnorm_1 = BatchNormalization()
        self.maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)

        self.conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
        self.batchnorm_2 = BatchNormalization()
        self.maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)


    def call(self, x):
        x = self.conv_1(x)
        x = self.batchnorm_1(x)
        x = self.maxpool_1(x)

        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.batchnorm_2(x)
        x = self.maxpool_2(x)

        return x

#Calling and using the class
feature_extractor = FeatureExtractor()

func_input = Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), name="Input_Image")

x = feature_extractor(func_input)
```

And it does indeed run flawlessly. But then I realized that in `__init__()`, the `BatchNormalization()` and `MaxPool2D()` look the same but are defined twice instead of being reused, so I did some research and [asked on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936987/arent-instances-in-init-reuseable) and came to the conclusion that **when layers are called in `call()`, they adapt to the dimension of the input, and then keep that dimension for later calls**, which prevents these layers to being able to be reused.

But as Fynn pointed out in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936987/arent-instances-in-init-reuseable), the `maxpool` member can actually be reused, while `batchnorm` cannot. So some layers adapt to the dimension of the input (like `batchnorm`) and some don't (like `maxpool`)? Or is there a property of these layers that causes this behavior? (that I can look up in the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, some layers have parameters, and those cannot be re-used, except in some edge cases, but they probably shouldn't. In this concrete example, batch normalization has learnable `beta` and `gamma` parameters, as well as non-trainable parameters that are used in inference (if this doesn't mean anything to you, I suggest looking up how batch norm works in detail).

Now, one layer object only has one set of parameters, and if you were to re-use that object, the same parameters would be applied in multiple places. Consider this:

```
self.conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 6, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
self.batchnorm = BatchNormalization()
self.maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)

self.conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
self.maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)
```

and assume `batchnorm` would be used after *both* convolutions. In this example, `batchnorm` would be built to have 6 betas/gammas because that's the number of filters in the first layer; trying to re-use it for the second layer would not work, as that has 16 filters, requiring 16 betas/gammas. This is why only creating one batchnorm layer doesn't work.

The following should actually run:

```
self.conv_1 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
self.batchnorm = BatchNormalization()
self.maxpool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)

self.conv_2 = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 4, padding = "valid", activation = "relu")
self.maxpool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides=2)
```

I changed it such that both convolutions use 16 filters. However, this would re-use the *same* beta/gamma after both layers (since we use the same batchnorm object), which is probably a bad idea.

For maxpool, this is not an issue, since it doesn't have any parameters. Pooling with the same window size and stride works the same for any input.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot I get it now! The learnable params are exactly the answer to my problem. Appreciate it:D

Comment: Welcome. In general, I would recommend just always creating new layers to prevent any chance of this happening. The layers that could be re-used are usually things like pooling or activation functions, which are pretty light-weight anyway (no parameters etc.) so there should be little harm in creating multiple objects.